# How to set an equality constraint like y = max(x1,x2,x3) in our MIP problem with or-tools?

Tags: python, python-3.x, or-tools

I work with or-tools to solve an MIP problem and I would like to add a constaint where a variable y is equal to the maximum among other variables Xi. For example : y = max(x1,x2,x3). Is there any max function in or-tools to do this?

I could add 4 constraints like :

```
y >= x1
y >= x2
y >= x3
y <= MAX  # where MAX is the upper bound of y.
```

But there could be a wrong situation where

```
x3 >= y.
```

Comment: you mean `max([x1,x2,x3])`?

Comment: yes! That's what I mean.

Comment: This does not work. Python interpret the max() and does not pass it to the solver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the max() operator of python does not work.
You should have a look at the literature

See: https://www.leandro-coelho.com/how-to-linearize-max-min-and-abs-functions/

Comment: Great answer. Now how would I consider the max() among more than 2 variables?

Answer (score -3):

Just put it into some simple structure, like:

-tuple `max((x1,x2,x3))`

-list `max([x1,x2,x3])`

-or set `max({x1,x2,x3})`

Last case is the best, becouse eliminate duplicates before checking difference.

Comment: I didn't know we could simply use max(). I tought there was a particular function from the library. For example, Gurobi has his own function grb.max_(). I'll try this! Thanks!

Comment: I tried and got the following ValueError: Operators "<" and ">" not supported with the linear solver. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Because python interpret max() as a set of function. It does not pass it to the solver.